# Web scraping GWT RPC and json attachment

Tags: php, json, gwt, web-scraping

I got stuck on this problem with web scraping a remote website using PHP and cURL. In a nutshell my php script makes a POST request method with the following GWT-RPC string.

> `7|0|4|http://www.ecommerce.com/|9617618FB1048F9E5610D4CE80D3CE78|com.ecommerce.service.auth.ShoppingRpcService|getSlotsStatus|1|2|3|4|0|`

and the server returns `Content-disposition: attachment;` and `Content-Type: application/json;` but when I check the data with json_decode function it returns NULL. Here the pastebin of the data
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=QpYTFEe2 and of course it does not seem a json object. What it is? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The website you're scraping lies. The output is not valid [JSON](http://json.org/). The whole first line looks invalid. The first 4 characters `//OK` have no business being there. Additionally `'` is not a valid string seperator.

You can trim the first 4 characters, replace `'` by `"`" and hope for the best.